# Search for unknown filenames with known extension on folder

Tags: php

How to search on folder if a know the extension of files but dont know the filename.

presume i have a folder with files like this.

```
folder/1.txt
folder/2.txt
folder/3.txt
```

using this simple method i echo all the files wich filenames contains only numbers.

```
  for ($i=0; $i<=3; $i++) {
  $files = 'folder/'. $i .'.txt';

  echo "$i.txt <br />";;
```

and the above code echo something like this

```
 1.txt
 2.txt
 3.txt
```

is possible to achieve if filenames contains letters? or even better letters and numbers.

```
aaa.txt
asdwe.txt
1asw2.txt
```

is this possible?

Comment: 1. Loop over the files in a directory. 2. Use `substr` or a similar function to get the last 4 characters of the file name. 3. Check if the last characters match your file extension. There is quite a lot of good information on this if you search Google for your question title...

Comment: Or just use `$files = glob('*.txt')`: http://php.net/glob

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv where to add the folder name here `$files = glob('*.txt')` where do this perform the search in wich folder? i want to search in the folder with name `folder` . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do that with `DirectoryIterator`:

```
<?php

const DS = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

$dir = new DirectoryIterator('your' . DS . 'direcory' . DS);

foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {

  if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
    // relative url of file = $fileinfo->getPathname();
    // file name  = $fileinfo->getFilename();
    echo $fileinfo->getFilename() . '<br />';
  }

}
```